# Android AWS Notes Tutorial | URI error

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, uri

I'm following along the AWS tutorial for a notes app ([link here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/tutorial-android-aws-mobile-notes-setup.html)). Everything was going smoothly until I added in DynamoDB. I have followed every step of the tutorial, but am getting an error when I try to save a new note. [Here](https://pastebin.com/9SGpQUqb) is a pastebin of the logcat output from android studio, and its pasted below.

I was wondering if anyone could look at the tutorial and the error log to see if they could help me figure out what I did wrong. I need to understand how to do this for a school project eventually, so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
03-27 17:20:35.300 2331-2415/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes E/CRASH: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
                                                                         at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:111)
                                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1402)
                                                                         at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:100)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-27 17:20:35.300 2331-2415/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes E/CRASH: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
03-27 17:20:35.300 2331-2415/com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncQueryWorker
                                                                              Process: com.amazonaws.mobile.samples.notes, PID: 2331
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:111)
                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1402)
                                                                                  at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:100)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Some basic debugging is needed here as the stack trace indicates that all the error is outside of the provided code.  (a) What version of Android Studio are you using?  (b) Put a breakpoint on line 133 (ish) of the NoteDetailFragment.java - it's at the start of saveDate() method.  Step through the function.  What content resolver function is being called and what is the itemUri value at that point?

Comment: I'm not home to do so right now, and I honestly don't know how to do all that in Android Studio. If you would be willing to test it for me, here's a link to the project. https://mega.nz/#!PVIC2Zpb!bYjtRJHkD3DENKg3b984Wo_QKaXYQqgvAA7sKgr9q_Q

Comment: That is your first task, then.  You need to learn how to use the tools.  We've formulated the tutorial so that it's fairly bullet proof.  When we have seen issues, it's because something has been misplaced or mistyped.  Running through basic debugging is generally enough to identify the issue.  The following page from the Android developer site discusses debugging in Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the project.  There is a line in the `NotesContentProvider.java` file at line 185 that builds the URI of the new note.  Replace the code with this:

```
DynamoDBMapper dbMapper = AWSProvider.getInstance().getDynamoDBMapper();
final NotesDO newNote = toNotesDO(values);
dbMapper.save(newNote);
Uri item = NotesContentContract.Notes.uriBuilder(newNote.getNoteId());
notifyAllListeners(item);
return item;
```

For you, it's probably more important to understand how I found this.  Firstly, there is an ApplicationCrashHandler.java class.  In there is a line that says "Place a breakpoint here".  I did that to trap the stack trace (although the full stack trace is displayed).  This told me that the `notifyListeners(uri)` was the cause, within the NotesContentProvider and during an insert (not others).  I next set a breakpoint on the insert within the NotesContentProvider, re-ran the app, and added a new note. Once the breakpoint was hit, I stepped through the code and watched the variables.

The thing I noticed was that the URI was mal-formed.  Specifically, content provider URIs start with `content://`.  The URI of the variable started with `/content`, which is not a valid URI.  Since I wrote the code, I know that there is a uriBuilder method within the content contract.  I used that to create the appropriate URI.

If you intend to progress in any sort of development, you need to understand how to debug the programs you are working with.  That means learning the tools that you are using.